# Are there any sites that have collection of Bellcomm Inc. memos?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight

Bellcomm Inc was contracted by NASA to provide alternate and hypothetical launch vehicles, spacecraft, and missions. The memos combine  the right blend of technical detail without heavy mathematics and are fantastic reading. I know they are now physically located in Washington D.C. but are there any sites online that may contain large numbers of the memos in .pdf form?

Comment: The https://falsesteps.wordpress.com/ has a wide variety of that type of material from many contractors.

Comment: Thanks. I've canvassed that site quite a bit, but  it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you note the Smithsonian has a collection of 222 boxes of the documentation, a list of which is here:
https://sova.si.edu/record/NASM.XXXX.0093

Online your best resource will probably be NTRS (NASA Technical Reports Server):
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=Bellcomm

Specifically with reference to Launch:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=Bellcomm%20launch

(I realize that this is mostly links, but that appears to be the answer to your question)